# How to move checkbox from left to right in JQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, mobile

I use http://jsfiddle.net/d8KNF/100/ to render my listview in jquery mobile, but I want to move this checkbox to right....I can't make it with data-iconpos, I see how is change but I can't think how to do IT. When I inspect elements with Chrome and change class btn-icon-left to  btn-icon-right in dynamicly generated label I'ts ok, but I can't add this class because the label is generated dynamicly.

#### advanced-customization-jquery-mobile-buttons

Advanced Customization of the jQuery Mobile Buttons | Appcropolis

#### adding many buttons to header in JQuery Mobile

Comment: I'd go ask people over in UX (user experience) if it's good idea to change the design to provide checkboxes that way. Unconventional can be bad if it confuses.

Answer (score 2):

Try to define fieldset like this

```
<fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-iconpos="right">
```

It is used from Jquery Mobile [official documentation](http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.0/docs/widgets/checkbox/)

Comment: This reslove my problem. Thank you

Comment: @Emil Georgiev, your welcome. Can you please accept this answer?